# Is it possible to have 2 ports open on SSH with 2 different authentication schemes?

Tags: login, sshd, key-authentication, authorization

I'm currently trying to set up an SSH server so that access to it from outside the network is ONLY allowed using an SSH Key and does not allow access to root or by any other username/password combination.

At the same time, internal users inside the network, still need to be able to connect to the same system, but expect to log in in the more traditional sense with a user name and password.

Users both external & internal will be accessing the system from windows using PuttySSH and the external access will be coming into the system via a port forwarding firewall that will open the source port to the outside world on some arbitrarily chosen high numbered port like 55000 (or what ever the admins decide)

The following diagram attempts to show the traffic flows better.

[image: SSH Setup]

I know how to set up the actual login to only use keys, and I know how to deny root, what I don't know is how to separate the two login types.

I had considered running two copies of SSHD listening on different ports on the same IP and having two different configurations for each port.

I also considered setting up a "match" rule, but I'm not sure if I can segregate server wide configurations using those options.

Finally, the external person logging in will always be the same user let's call them "Frank" for the purposes of this question, so "Frank" will only ever be allowed to log in from the external IP, and never actually be sat in front of any system connecting internally, where as every other user of the system will only ever connect internally, and never connect from an external IP.

Franks IP that he connects from is a dynamically assigned one but the public IP he is connecting too is static and will never change, the internal IP of the port forwarder like wise will also never change and neither will the internal IP address of the SSH server.

Internal clients will always connect from an IP in the private network range that the internal SSH servers IP is part of and is a 16 bit mask EG: 192.168.0.0/16

Is this set up possible, using one config file and one SSH server instance?  If so, how do I do it?

or

Am I much better using 2 running servers with different config?

For ref the SSH server is running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Untested, but look into using "Match LocalPort 22" to segregate config options.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, will do.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I used to use Match address, and it works

Comment: @JeffSchaller yep I was just reading up on that your "Match port 22" lead me in a direction I'd not yet explored, and as such have discovered that "match host" may be better as the external inbound and local use different domain addresses to reach them.

Comment: @JeffSchaller with your pointers in these comments I was able to figure out how to do it, and without needing to use 2 ports :-)    Now I guess I'll need to write up my own answer, unless of course you would like to take the points ...  I did it using "Match Host" instead

Comment: Happy to hear you got it figured out! I'd be happy for you to post your own answer!

Comment: no worries... will do :-)

Comment: Lax security on internal networks is an antiquated paradigm.   Passwords aren't desirable anyway,  ago its argue it's worth considering just having pub key auth on all sides and be done with it

Comment: Yup, don't disagree with you there, except these users are running scripts for server processes that they've been using for years, and many have hard coded credentials in them.  Eventually in future I may get chance to change things, but for now this is they way it needs to be done in order to cause the least amount of chaos.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So, it turns out the answer was actually way, way simpler than I thought it would be.

I do however have to thank '@jeff schaller' for his comments, if it hadn't of been for him I wouldn't have started looking into how the SSH 'Match' configuration works.

Anyway

The trick is to set your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file up as default to be the configuration you would like to have for the access coming in from the external internet connection.

In my case, this meant setting the following

```
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

By doing this, I'm forcing ALL logins no matter where they come from to need to be key based logins using an SSH key.

I then on the windows machines used 'PuttyGen' to generate a public/private key pair which I saved to disk, and an appropriate ssh entry for my "authorized_hosts" file in the external users home directory.

I pasted this ssh key into the correct place in my users home folder, then set putty up to use the private (ppk) file generated by PuttyGen for log in and saved the profile.

I then saved the profile, and sent that and the ppk key file to the external user using a secure method (Encrypted email with a password protected zip file attached)

Once the user had the ppk and profile in their copy of putty and could log in, I then added the following as the last 2 lines on my sshd_config file

```
Match Host server1,server1.internalnet.local,1.2.3.4
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

In the "Match" line I've changed the server names to protect the names of my own servers.

Note each server domain is separated by a comma and NO SPACES, this is important.  If you put any spaces in it causes SSHD to not load the config and report an error, the 3 matches I have in there do the following:

**server1** - matches on anyone using just 'server1' with no domain to connect EG: 'fred@server1'

**server1.internalnet.local** - matches on anyone using the fully qualified internal domain name EG: 'fred@server1.internalinternet.local' (NOTE: you will need an internal DNS to make this work correctly)

**1.2.3.4** - matches on the specific I.P. address assigned to the SSH server EG: 'fred@1.2.3.4' this can use wild cards, or even better net/mask cidr format EG: 1.2.* or 192.168.1.0/8 if you do use wild cards however, please read fchurca's answer below for some important notes.

If any of the patterns provided match the host being accessed, then the one and only single change to be made to the running config is to turn back on the ability to have an interactive password login.

You can also put other config directives in here too, and those directives will also be turned back on for internal hosts listed in the match list.

do however read this:

https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5

carefully, as not every configuration option is allowed to be used inside a match block, I found this out when I tried to "UsePAM yes" to turn PAM authentication back on, only to be told squarely that wasn't allowed.

Once you've made your changes, type

```
sshd -T
```

followed by return to test them before attempting to restart the server, it'll report any errors you have.

In addition to everything above, I got a lot of help from the following two links too:

https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Limit_access_to_openssh_features_with_the_Match_keyword.html

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/match-address-sshd_config-allow-root-loginfrom-one_ip_address-on-linux-unix/

Comment: Couldn't a (possibly nefarious) external user set up their own local DNS that resolves "server1" to your server's public IP, and then be able to use password instead of public key authentication?

Comment: I guess they could, but it wouldn't within the grasp of your regular user they would need a fair bit of knowledge, and they would need to know what the internal DNS/Domain/server name is too.  I've deliberately set the external name to be very different to the internal one, so to make an attack like that they would need pre existing knowledge from inside the network.  I'm happy that the general 3rd party user, using this wouldn't have the skills to do this.

Comment: If general users were what were needed to worry about,  computer security would be easier.

Comment: @pericynthion wouldn’t the sshd server itself need to be given that DNS response?

Comment: @Wildcard no not in my case.  I have the external domain name that's attached to the external IP, and that's controlled by an entirely separate DNS server that belongs to my domain registrar, the internal server name is registered in my own DNS server that sits on the inside of the firewall and allows me to assign any domains/hosts etc to any I.P in my internal net that I want.  The internal never sends local requests out, the external never sees inside, they both stay on their own side of the firewall.  Any domain names that the internal cannot satisfy from it's own setup are passed to my ISP

Comment: shawty, that doesn't make sense.  The `Match` line in this case controls which hosts can *connect* to you without keys.  To use hostnames at all in that line, you have to have `UseDNS` set to `yes` which means that *sshd itself* "should look up the remote host name, and to check that the resolved host name for the remote IP address maps back to the very same IP address."  Which means to exploit that an attacker would have to control what DNS responses *your server* gets, not their own.  Which is why I don't understand what @pericynthion's attack model is.

Comment: @wildcard - ah, I see what your saying :-) ok, I'll try fit this into a comment, but you might be better off coming and finding me on LinkedIn or Twitter for a longer explanation.  If you, inside your local network have your OWN DNS server, and all the requests for any DNS are sent through your local server, you can intercept any request you want and return any IP address you see fit. So imagine my external is 'external.example.com' and internally it's 'internal.example.local' if I know the IP address of 'external.example.com' there is nothing stopping me from setting the IP  (cont)

Comment: from the external address, against the internal name inside my own local DNS server.  The result would then be, if I queried 'internal.example.local' i would in actual fact get the address of 'external.example.com', if that's all there was to it, it wouldn't be a problem however, but the SSH client will then attempt to connect to that IP address, but will set the host name to the one it resolved, namely 'internal.example.local' and so the SSH server would actually apply the rules for the internal connection and allow username/password style logins.

Comment: in order for the attack to be successful however, you a) Need to know how to set up and operate a DNS server correctly b) Know exactly what the internal names are that the server internally responds to and c) Actually know that the SSH server is in fact configured to switch on password based logins, only (a) is achievable from the outside without internal knowledge of the target network.  It is a potential security risk, for sure, but it's a fairly low risk and is only going to be exploited by that 0.5% who actually understand it and think it's worth their trouble to exploit.

Comment: for the 99.5% out there that are just looking for ways to get malware into a system to steal data or extort a target is offers to high of a barrier to be generally useful and easy to get into.

Comment: Ah, so if they can spoof your *internal* DNS, *while* they are connecting from an external host, then they could use passwords instead of keys when they're not supposed to.  That makes sense.  But that wouldn't be purely an "external user" in the sense I took it from @pericynthion's comment.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @shawty isn't this a classic instance of security by obscurity? I believe generally people just use a terminal server to get into a network, which has special configuration for being externally-facing.

Comment: @Nacht maybe, it depends entirely on which way you look at it.  The barrier here is so high for your common user that in most cases it's not worth them exploiting it when there is easier targets to pick on.  It's like the age old saying "Door locks and alarms are only there to keep good people out", if someone wants in, and the reward for doing so is greater than the effort there willing to put in to achieving that goal, then their going to get in no matter how good your defenses are.

Comment: besides, the other part of the deal I've not mentioned yet, is that the file system on the entire box is locked down to an absurd level, that even the root user has to perform certain tasks before they can do anything useful on some folders.  The normal users have 0 write access to any of the folders they have access too, the log in is for one reason and one reason only and that's to sftp a single file (A report/Log of some processes) across to an external system for processing, so I'm fairly confident that if anyone did decide it was worth their effort, they ain't getting very far once in

Comment: pericynthion - you operate under wrong assumption, it is a `sshd` server who resolves the hostname for `Host` locally using it's DNS resolver and not a connectig client - can you please explain to us how do you imagine attacker spoofing his local DNS server?

Comment: @Nacht I think it's rather issue of you not completely understanding the setup discussed - there is no obscurity here. Please revise DNS resolution.

Comment: @shawty there are two ways around this literally "impossible exploit", the others are still pondering (yes, it's practically so impossible, that you won't really have any problems as you correctly assumed). This is different problem from the one fchurca@ spotted and two are related, but not the same. 1st solution, we big boys use, is to have 3rd (4th depending on the country) DNS subdomain, ie. infra.mydomain.com. And ensure that at your split DNS handler (I presume you are using `dnsmasq`) anything below infra.mydomain.com never ever gets forwarded outside to the external DNS servers.

Comment: @shawty one thing: I see you are using `.local`. Never use `.local`. This name is reserved for too many things by now, and you will fuck up your infrastructure in the future, if you are bent on using it. It is usully deranged widows admins who like `.local` and did not get the memo from Microsoft somehow yet, that it is forbidden to use.

Comment: @shawty second solution is to use `Match Address` as suggested below, which is insanely better. More over that way you can also set `UseDNS` to `no` which makes your `sshd` accept logins quickly even if local DNS resolver or your local infrastructural DNS handler fails totally. It's a big difference during emergencies to be able to login into SSH within 1 second, instead of waiting a minute (or what is the DNS reslution timeout) staring at the login prompt.

Answer (score 8):

> 1.2.* - matches on anyone in the local net using any address assigned to the SSH server that's in the 16 bit net mask for the server EG: 'fred@1.2.3.4'

Careful! Pattern matching in .ssh/config is based on string globbing, not necessarily ip addresses. According to the same manpage you are reading:

> PATTERNS
>
> A pattern consists of zero or more non-whitespace characters, ‘*’ (a wildcard that matches zero or more characters), or ‘?’ (a wildcard that matches exactly one character). For example, to specify a set of declarations for any host in the “.co.uk” set of domains, the following pattern could be used:
>
> `Host *.co.uk`
>
> The following pattern would match any host in the 192.168.0.[0-9] network range:
>
> `Host 192.168.0.?`

If somebody tries to login from an IP that publicly reverse-resolves to `1.2.badguy.com` , it will match your `1.2.*` rule.

https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5#PATTERNS

[Updated for completeness]

As noted elsewhere, you can use `Match Address 1.2.0.0/16` instead of `Match Host 1.2.*`

[/Update]

Comment: I haven't tested this, but reading the documentation suggests that this could be done better by using `Match Address 1.2.0.0/16`.

Comment: Noted thanks.  What I've actually done internally is 1.2.3.4 and set it to the specific I.P address assigned to that specific server.  I added it in my answer above just for illustration that it could be done more than anything.  In hindsight I may actually change it.

Comment: If possible, always prefer locally knowable knowledge (i.e. one that does not not need remote resolution) against remotely obtained knowledge (i.e. DNS query). Unfortunately gethostname() and getnameinfo() (unless with NI_NAMEREQD) can always return numeric hostname (i.e. IP) if DNS does not resolve - which I believe is an erroneous design. Case in point, example in answer above. When you use `Match Address` the sshd will use getaddrinfo() instead, by which client address is lifted directly from peer of the socket and thus cannot be spoofed. So `Match Address` is substantially "safer".

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should be looking into is splitting out your ssh configs.  For example; setup your /etc/ssh/ssh_config to have the global variables you need for all users by default (ssh key auth, port forwarding, etc...).

Then if your user (let's call him Bob) has a local (or nfs mounted) home directory, put a config just for him in /home/bob/.ssh/.  This config will contain your match statement as well as if you need him to connect with a password rather then a cert as well as his own keep alive values, etc...

I have done this in the past and presently to lock down certain local accounts to come in from only one IP address and only allow cert based authentication while other user accounts may instead be using PAM authentication and have password based authentication.

In short, building and maintaining separate user config files based on user need is easier to manage than trying to keep it all under the default config file for ssh.

Comment: Note that ~/.ssh/config will have no effect on incoming connections, it is only used by ssh for outgoing connections. It is not read by sshd.

Comment: please expand your answer on how you do path expansion in your SERVER config, as your answer confuses neophytes (by code fragment). Second putting server read configs into user's home, unless owned by root, and even then, is a security risk, as your user might learn and potentially change their configs without your approval. If I am not mistaken server does some rudimentary access right checking, but I would not bet on it. Never put server read user configs into the user's dirs.